# Can "Contributions - Recurring Billing Updates" and similar messages be turned off?

Tags: civicontribute, recurring-contributions, system-workflow-messages

We'd like to turn off Contributions - Recurring Cancellation Notification, Contributions - Recurring Billing Updates, and Contributions - Recurring Start and End Notification. We don't want the messages to be sent.

Generally, we update people's billing information from the backend. In this case, we don't want to send confirmation messages automatically. Sometimes we have to cancel a recurring donation and create it again to get the right financial type, etc. and in that case we definitely don't want email notifications going to donors!

Is there any way to entirely disable all these notifications?

Answer (score 1):

This is untested but in hook_civicrm_alterMailParams you can check `$params['messageTemplateID']` and if it's one you care about set `$params['abortMailSend'] = TRUE`.